# Xerces 3.2 XMLString::transcode not working on special characters

Tags: c++, encoding, xerces, iconv, transcode

I have this xml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<cmh>
<value atr="éè€ç"></value> 
</cmh>
```

And this simple C++ program using Xerces 3.2.3:

```cpp
...
//const XMLCh* xmlch_OptionA = currentElement->getAttribute(XMLString::transcode("atr")); --> this one always works
char* a =  "éèç€";
//char* a =  XMLString::transcode(xmlch_OptionA); --> this one does not work with these characters
cout << sizeof(char) << " " << a << std::endl;
cout << std::hex << (unsigned int)(a[0] &0xFF) << " " << (unsigned int)(a[1] &0xFF) << " " << (unsigned int)(a[2] &0xFF) << " " << (unsigned int)(a[3] &0xFF) << std::endl;
...
```

Output:

```
1 éèç€
c3 a9 c3 a8
```

This program works just fine but when I try to retrieve the char* from the XML file with XMLString:transcode (see the commented lines), I get nothing and I can't figure out why. I built this Xerces with Iconv as its transcoder, isn't it supposed to correctly handle these situations? Or maybe is there a way to achieve the same result without using transcode()?

Wrong output:

```
1
0 0 0 0
```

NB: Of course, it works if I replace the "éèç€" by something like "abcd".

Comment: It seems your `a` contains **8** UTF-8 bytes seen as 8 chars! However `transcode` uses a two-byte XMLCh. So `"\u00E9\u00E8\u00E7\u20AC"`.

Comment: I think you're missing the point here. The uncommented line whether with "éèç€" or "\u00E9\u00E8\u00E7\u20AC"  does work, it is the commented line which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was coming from the Docker image I was using (gcc:10.2).
The locale for en_US.UTF-8 was not installed on it.
So, I installed it and wrote at the beginning of my program:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

XMLString::transcode works just fine now.